# graphQL query using cURL

Tags: curl, graphql

This query has been tested in Postman and is valid.  With cURL, I am getting 400/malformed no matter what I try.

```
query {
  products {
    complexity
    request_id
    data(first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
        id
        sku
        name
        warehouse_products {
          id 
          warehouse_id
          on_hand
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --data '{"query":"query { products { complexity request_id data(first: 100) { edges { node { id sku name warehouse_products { id warehouse_id on_hand}}}}}}"}' https://public-api.shiphero.com/graphql
```

I've tried just about every permutation on this syntax that I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your GraphQL explorer (ex: GraphiQL or Apollo Studio) to generate the curl command for a query. Can you try:

```
curl --request POST \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    --url https://public-api.shiphero.com/graphql \
    --data '{"query":"query {\n  products {\n    complexity\n    request_id\n    data(first: 100) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n        id\n        sku\n        name\n        warehouse_products {\n          id \n          warehouse_id\n          on_hand\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  }\n}","variables":{}}' \
```